# How can I display differently from the database a field from a record, after the execution of a SELECT statement?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, crystal-reports

I created a Crystal Reports report viewer in my WindowsForm application. When the form that contains the report viewer is loaded, the data is loaded into the report using the a fill method created from the TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard. There is a column in my database which the type is a single bit. So when the report loads, it shows True or False, depending of what is saved in the database. I would like to know how to display the string "Cheque" in the report when the field is set to True and the string "Duplicata" when the field is set to false. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the SQL that the TableAdapter uses to format the result for you, or you could probably use Crystal Reports to do the formatting.

If you wanted to do it in the actual SQL statement, something like the following would work

```
SELECT (CASE [ColumnName] WHEN 1 THEN 'Cheque' ELSE 'Duplicata' END) as [AliasName]
FROM [TableName]
```

Comment: I got the following error: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Comment: SELECT
  Titulo.codigo, Titulo.valor, Titulo.tipo , Titulo.vencimento, Sacado.nome AS sacado_nome, Cliente.nome AS cliente_nome, Cliente.documento
FROM 
  Titulo 
    INNER JOIN Cliente ON Titulo.cliente_id = Cliente.id
    INNER JOIN Sacado ON Titulo.sacado_id = Sacado.id
WHERE Titulo.tipo = 'True' AND Titulo.data_base BETWEEN data1 AND data2

Comment: 'Titulo', 'Cliente' and 'Sacado' are tables. +++ 'Titulo.tipo' is the field that I was talking about +++ data1 and data2 are parameters.

Comment: @Bruno Your parameters need to have @ in from them (@data1, @data2). Also, is Titulo.tipo a bit column or char/varchar?  Last point, in this query only rows with Titulo.tipo = 'True' are returned, so in your select statement you could omit the Titulo.tipo column and just have `SELECT Titulo.codigo, TItulo.valor, 'Cheque' as tipo, Titulo.vencimento...`

Comment: The SELECT Titulo.codigo, TItulo.valor, 'Cheque' as tipo, Titulo.vencimento... worked very well. Thank you very much.